# Why does Color view seem to fade faster than Image view in SwiftUI?

Tags: animation, swiftui, opacity

I have the following code where the contents of my SplashScreen fade out smoothly. But it seems as if the Color("app_color") view fades out faster than the Image view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabbedView()
            SplashScreen (duration: 2.0, delay: 2.0) {
                SplashContents()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SplashContents: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("app_color")
            Image("app_logo")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
    }
}

public struct SplashScreen<Content: View>: View {
    
    @State private var showSplash = true
    
    let duration: Double
    let delay: Double
    let content: Content
    
    public init(duration: Double = 0, delay: Double = 0, @ViewBuilder contentProvider: () -> Content){
        self.duration = duration
        self.delay = delay
        self.content = contentProvider()
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        content
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .opacity(showSplash ? 1 : 0)
            .zIndex(0) //push this screen to the back
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: duration)) {
                            showSplash = false
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The result can be seen in the attached video.

[image: Fade]

So in the video, you can obviously see the square image is separate from the red background because they seem to fade at different rates. My question is, how do I get the Color view to fade at the same rate as the Image view so that it looks like the image and color views are a single item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's not that the image is fading slower, rather that they overlap. You can think of it as having your red color twice in that image area.

One way to have them rendered together is by using the modifier `compositingGroup()`.

```
ZStack {
    Color("app_color")
    Image("app_logo")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
}
.compositingGroup()
```

> A compositing group makes compositing effects in this view’s ancestor views, such as opacity and the blend mode, take effect before this view is rendered.

> Use compositingGroup() to apply effects to a parent view before applying effects to this view.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group/compositinggroup()).